# Align equations: What is wrong here?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

```
\begin{align*}
\text{Mean: }\\
E[Y] & = f(y) \cdot 0 + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} f(y)\cdot y\\
& = [p_i + (1-p_i)e^{-\lambda_i}] \cdot 0 + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (1-p_i)\frac{e^{-\lambda_i}\lambda_i^y}{y!} \cdot y\\
& = 0 + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (1-p_i)\frac{e^{-\lambda_i}\lambda_i^y}{y!} \cdot y\\
& = (1-p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} [\lambda_i+\frac{2\lambda_i^2}{2!}+\frac{3\lambda_i^3}{3!}+....]\\
& = (1-p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \lambda_i [1+\frac{\lambda_i}{1!}+\frac{\lambda_i^2}{2!}+....]\\
& = (1-p_i)\lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i}e^{\lambda}\\
& = (1-p_i)\lambda.\\
\text{Variance: }\\
E[Y^2] & = f(y) \cdot 0 + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} f(y)\cdot y^2\\
& = [p_i + (1-p_i)e^{-\lambda_i}] \cdot 0 + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (1-p_i)\frac{e^{-\lambda_i}\lambda_i^y}{y!} \cdot y^2\\
& = 0 + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (1-p_i)\frac{e^{-\lambda_i}\lambda_i^y}{y!} \cdot y^2\\
& = (1-p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} [\lambda_i+\frac{4\lambda_i^2}{2!}+\frac{9\lambda_i^3}{3!}+\frac{16\lambda_i^4}{4!}+\frac{25\lambda_i^5}{5!}+....]\\
& = (1-p_i) e^{-\lambda_i}[\lambda_i+(\lambda_i^2+\lambda_i^2)+(\frac{\lambda_i^3}{2!}+\lambda_i^3)+(\frac{\lambda_i^4}{3!} \\
+\frac{\lambda_i^4}{2!}+)+(\frac{\lambda_i^5}{4!}+\frac{\lambda_i^5}{3!})+....]\\
& = (1-p_i)e^{-\lambda_i} [\lambda_i(1+\lambda_i+\frac{\lambda_i^2}{2!} + \frac{\lambda_i^3}{3!}+.....)+\lambda_i^2(1+\lambda_i+\frac{\lambda_i^2}{2!} + \frac{\lambda_i^3}{3!}+.....)]\\
& = (1-p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} [\lambda_ie^{\lambda_i}+\lambda_i^2 e^{\lambda}]\\
& = (1-p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} e^{\lambda_i} (\lambda_i+\lambda_i^2) \\
& = (1-p_i)(\lambda_i+\lambda_i^2)\\
V[Y]= E[y^2]-(E[y])^2 = (1-p_i)(\lambda_i+\lambda_i^2) - ((1-p_i)\lambda)^2.
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Mmmm, it depends. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: If you find some of the answers useful, you should consider to accept one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a guess (since you haven't told us what the problem is):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent Mean:
\begin{align*}
E[Y]
& = f(y) \cdot 0 + \sum_{y=1}^\infty f(y) \cdot y\\
& = \left[p_i + (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i}\right] \cdot 0 + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}(1 - p_i) \frac{e^{-\lambda_i} \lambda_i^y}{y!} \cdot y\\
& = 0 + \sum_{y=1}^\infty (1 - p_i) \frac{e^{-\lambda_i} \lambda_i^y}{y!} \cdot y\\
& = (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \left[\lambda_i + \frac{2\lambda_i^2}{2!} + \frac{3\lambda_i^3}{3!}+\dots\right]\\
& = (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \lambda_i \left[1 + \frac{\lambda_i}{1!} + \frac{\lambda_i^2}{2!}+\dots\right]\\
& = (1 - p_i) \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i} e^{\lambda}\\
& = (1 - p_i) \lambda.
\intertext{Variance:}
E\left[Y^2\right]
& = f(y) \cdot 0 + \sum_{y=1}^\infty f(y) \cdot y^2\\
& = \left[p_i + (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i}\right] \cdot 0 + \sum_{y=1}^\infty (1 - p_i) \frac{e^{-\lambda_i} \lambda_i^y}{y!} \cdot y^2\\
& = 0 + \sum_{y=1}^\infty (1 - p_i) \frac{e^{-\lambda_i} \lambda_i^y}{y!} \cdot y^2\\
& = (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \left[\lambda_i + \frac{4\lambda_i^2}{2!} + \frac{9\lambda_i^3}{3!} + \frac{16\lambda_i^4}{4!} + \frac{25\lambda_i^5}{5!} + \dots\right]\\
& = (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \biggl[\lambda_i + \left(\lambda_i^2 + \lambda_i^2\right) + \left(\frac{\lambda_i^3}{2!} + \lambda_i^3\right)\\
&\hphantom{{}= (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \biggl[} + \left(\frac{\lambda_i^4}{3!} + \frac{\lambda_i^4}{2!}\right) + \left(\frac{\lambda_i^5}{4!} + \frac{\lambda_i^5}{3!}\right) + \dots\biggr]\\
& = (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \biggl[\lambda_i \left(1 + \lambda_i + \frac{\lambda_i^2}{2!} + \frac{\lambda_i^3}{3!} + \dots\right)\\
&\hphantom{{}= (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \biggl[} + \lambda_i^2 \left(1 + \lambda_i + \frac{\lambda_i^2}{2!} + \frac{\lambda_i^3}{3!} + \dots\right)\biggr]\\
& = (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} \left[\lambda_i e^{\lambda_i} + \lambda_i^2 e^{\lambda}\right]\\
& = (1 - p_i) e^{-\lambda_i} e^{\lambda_i} \left(\lambda_i + \lambda_i^2\right)\\
& = (1 - p_i) \left(\lambda_i + \lambda_i^2\right).
\end{align*}
So we have
\begin{align*}
V[Y]
& = E\left[y^2\right] - (E[y])^2\\
& = (1 - p_i) \left(\lambda_i + \lambda_i^2\right) - ((1 - p_i)\lambda)^2.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I think it's fair to guess that the OP's main problems were the two missing `&` instances.

Comment: @Mico I _think_ you are right (but I would like to _know_ it). `:)`

Answer (score 6):

I'd say there are two main problems:

- You're missing an alignment symbol (`&`) in the final equation line, beginning with `V[Y]= E[y^2]-(E[y])^2`; fix it by inserting `&` before the first `=`.
- There's a very bad, and likely unnecessary, line break right before `+\frac{\lambda_i^4}{2!}`; I suggest removing that line break.

You should probably break up the very long `\align*` environment into two separate, shorter environments, one each for the mean and variance expressions. While you're at it, take the header lines (`Mean:` and `Variance`) out of the `align*` environments entirely.

Separately, you may want to replace all those `.....` and `....` instances with `\cdots`. Furthermore, you should probably increase the size of the square brackets in quite a few places, e.g., by using `\Bigl[` and `\Bigr]` judiciously. I wouldn't recommend using `\left[` and `\right]` since that will lead to "fence" symbols that are (typographically speaking) too large for their surroundings.

Comment: I think `\cdots` should be `\dots`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - In the present case the effect is the same. I suppose `\dotsb` (dots appropriate for binary operators...) would be the most idiomatic instruction. :-)

Comment: Hmmm; actually I didn't knew about `\dotsb`. The point of choosing `\dots` over `\cdots` is that the first can be chosen in general and then `amsmath` will take care of the rest.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - In the present case all three give the same result (and, for sure, look a whole lot better than `....`).